# Convert array of bytes into GUID while filling DataTable

Tags: c#, database, dataset, guid

I try to retreive data from `Oracle` db like:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (var cmd = DBOracle.GetCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;
    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

    adapter.Fill(ds);
}
```

The target table contains column with `GUID` but in `ds` this column is filled as array of bytes instead of GUID. Is it possible let `OracleDataAdapter` know that column type should be GUID?

Answer (score -1):

Try converting byte array to GUID and then load in to database

**Guid resultGuid = new Guid(byteArray);**

Comment: I know how to convert array of bytes into Guid, but I don't want to create new DataTable and convert each value in loop.